# find out date of last update (by maintainer) of an apt package

Tags: apt

As seen in the title, I am wondering whether it is possible to find out the date of last update (by maintainer) of an `apt` package. This way I can get a sense of whether the package is obsolete. I tried both `apt-cache show` or [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), but seems there is no such information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `apt-get changelog`, e.g.:

```
$ apt-get changelog unity

unity (5.20.0-0ubuntu2) precise; urgency=low

  * Check to see if the window is supposed to have decorations instead
    of the window actually being decorated when Undecorate() is called.
    This fixes a regression from the previous SRU where windows opened
    maximized upon login could have extra decorations (LP: #1195730)

 -- Christopher Townsend <christopher.townsend@canonical.com>  Mon, 08 Jul 2013 09:37:30 -0600

unity (5.20.0-0ubuntu1) precise; urgency=low
[...]
```